# Prove that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal iff $ab \in N \Leftrightarrow ba \in N . \forall a,b \in G $

Tags: abstract-algebra

Prove that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal iff $ab \in N \Leftrightarrow ba \in N . \forall a,b \in G $

___________________________________-

$\Leftarrow$ $ab \in N \iff  ba \in N , \forall a,b \in G$ then N is a normal

following the hint $a^{-1} n=b$ not sure but

$$n_1 g =(ab)g =(a a^{-1}n)g=n_1 g$$

$\Rightarrow $ $N$ is normal then $ab \in N \iff  ba \in N , \forall a,b \in G$

so $$gn_1=n_2 g$$

guessing that $n_1 =ab \in N$ not sure here  let $n_1 =ab??? $ ***lost***
so $$ g(ab)=n_2 g$$

---

Comment: if $N$ is normal, then $ab \in N$ implies $b(ab)b^{-1} = ba \in N$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $N$ satisfies $\forall a,b \in G ab \in N \Leftrightarrow ba \in N$
Then if $N \ni a =b(b^{-1}a) \Rightarrow b^{-1}ab \in N$, so N is normal.

If $N$ is normal, then $ab \in N \Rightarrow N \ni b(ab)b^{-1} = ba$.